# Replace Output html before rendered, remove attributes

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, output

I have a problem in an MVC site where I want to go through the Output html before its rendered to the page and do some regex-magic to remove some attributes and elements in the html and then "deliver" the "new" html to the page.

I have noticed that I can use an IResultFilter and add a Filter..
However.. in my own filter the only method that Im aware of is the Write method.. and it seems like ASP.net MVC delivers the html-bytes in chuks, depending on the size of the "final output".. but in my case this causes some problems.. since the chunk might get cut off any time in the html and might there for for instance cut off on the attribute that I want to match my regex against.. which then would end up with my regex not working properly.
..So.. is there anyway to get around the "chunks"-part and just run my regex against the entire html-output before its rendered and replace it with my modified html-markup?

Answer (score 0):

You can write an httpmodule for this and do your modifications in the OnEndRequest event. http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/post-processing-the-output-of-aspnet-pag/212001499

```
public void OnEndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication) sender;
    HttpContext ctx = app.Context;
    DoCustomProcessing(ctx.Response);
}
```

Comment: Yes, however.. this article still refers to the .Filter.. which I guess still will break down my output into chunks of byte-arrays depending on the size of the output-markup.. or am I incorrect?

Comment: It isn't the same kind of filter as mvc. Here is another link on the topic:http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120308-1.aspx. Here is one more I found: http://www.windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/10/20/httpfilter.html